# Delegate doesn't work using a container ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, containers, appdelegate, swift-protocols

In my MainViewController I have set up a button and a container view, which contains a SecondViewController:

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
secondViewController.willMove(toParent: self)
containerView.addSubview(secondViewController.view)
secondViewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
secondViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.addChild(secondViewController)
secondViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

I set up my delegation protocol:

```
protocol SayHiDelegate {
    func sayHi()
}
```

Inside MainViewController:

```
var delegate: SayHiDelegate?

@objc func buttonTapped() {
    delegate?.sayHi()
}
```

I set up the delegate function in my SecondViewController

```
func sayHi() {
    label.text = "HI"
}
```

In SecondViewcontroller viewDidLoad:

```
let vc = MainViewController()
vc.delegate = self
```

In this project I didn't use the storyboard.
The problem is that when I tap the button in my MainViewController the delegate function in called but doesn't work.
I think the problem should be using the container view and a delegate function.
[Here](https://file.io/xVWpyL) to download the project.
Any hints? Thanks

Comment: you should use delegate if the `SecondViewController` needed to notify `MainViewController`, not the other way around.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Why? is it wrong?

Comment: How do you expect `delegate?` to have a value from ?? assigned it ?? it's nil so code doesn't trigger inside the second vc no reference to it

Comment: @Sh_Khan I need to pass data between ViewControllers, so I decided to use delegate. The MainViewController has data that SecondViewControllers needs.

Comment: @EdoardodeCal Best way to notify from one controller to another by using delegate. use delegate as weak for preventing the retain cycle.

Comment: always think from the sender point in How you get a reference to the receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to call a child from a parent then no need for a delegate here , Make this an instance variable inside `MainViewController`

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
```

then use it to call

```
secondViewController.sayHi()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in you code

```
self.delegate = secondViewController
```

Check you delegate have nil because you din't assign a reference of **secondViewController**

Comment: the op is trying to call the second from main not vice vera

Comment: @SumitGarg thanks, but previously I set in my SecondViewController:         let vc = MainViewController()
        vc.delegate = self, and it didn't work. Using your code it works, why?

Comment: can you please clear, what type of reference is self contain,  it is SecondViewController type ?